# Issue with position relative div and absolute div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with width 750px and position relative, inside a child div with style position absolute. I want the child div make to width 950px.But the parent div (style positon relative)
not allowing that.What is the solution without change the child div's position?

```
<ul id="nav" class="grid_19 menu">
  <li> <a>HOME</a>
    <ul class="mgdd_dropdown">
      <li>
        <p>menu<br>
        </p>
        <p>menu</p>
        <p>menu</p>
        <p>menu</p>
      </li>
      <li class="mgdrp_list fff">
        <p>menu<br>
        </p>
        <p>menu</p>
        <p>menu</p>
        <p>menu</p>
      </li>
      <li class="mgdrp_list fff">
        <p>menu<br>
        </p>
        <p>menu</p>
        <p>menu</p>
        <p>menu</p>
      </li>
      <li class="mgdrp_list fff">
        <p>menu<br>
        </p>
        <p>menu</p>
        <p>menu</p>
        <p>menu</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>APPAREL</a> </li>
  <li>SHOES</li>
  <li>CUSTOMER SERVICE</li>
</ul>








 .grid_19
      {
       width:750px;
       display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        position: relative;
      }
```

Child div css

```
#nav ul.mgdd_dropdown 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #CCCCCC;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to this forum, now its corrected

Comment: You haven't added a width - just a min-width of 100px?

Comment: Why don't you just set `width: 900px` on `#nav ul.mgdd_dropdown`?

Comment: I don't understand how the code relates to the question, there are no divs or widths in that code example.  Here's a fiddle with your code in, it looks fine, can you modify it to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/EpxCb/

Comment: @SalmanA i have another div after the parent div, so i cant make 950px for the div

Comment: @JohnKiernander http://jsfiddle.net/EpxCb/1/

Comment: First of all, can you clean your codes first? `<li>` should have a parent `<ul>`

Comment: now its corrected both of they are ul, parent and child, please get me a solution

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, it is necessary that the child element was greater in width than the parent if yes then css here:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
    background: #ececec;
    height: 800px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.child {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    background: #c01;
    height: 500px;
    width: 950px;
    right: -15%;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EpxCb/)